# How to make monthly report

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I'm working with a system project where I can records fuel expenses,an attribute named amount from two different tables were already combined and the sum value in column is already coded using javascript, however there is one function that I need to code but I dont know how to do it, 
this function is displaying a mothly report, if I hit month of january, i want to display all values that was stored in the month of january.

this is how my html form constructed:(this is where I want to appear the modal when button hits, then give me a selection from january to february)

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3 align="center">Withdrawal Per Vehicle</h3>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <table id="expense_table"class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Plate Number</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach($Withdraw as $w): ?>
                                        <?= '<tr>' ?>
                                            <?= '<td class="rowDataSd">' . $w["carid"] . '</td>' ?>
                                            <?= '<td class="rowDataSd">' . $w["reg_num"] . '</td>' ?>
                                            <?= '<td class="rowDataSd">' . $w["amount"] . '</td>' ?>
                                        <?= '</tr>' ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <span id="val"></span>
                        </div>
```

this how the SQL statement sum all values from different tables:

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT tbl_vehicle.carid,
                                  tbl_vehicle.reg_num,
                                    IFNULL(tbl_fuel.sum_amount,0) + 
                                    IFNULL(tbl_maintenance.sum_amount,0)
                            AS amount
                            FROM tbl_vehicle tbl_vehicle
                            LEFT JOIN
                            (SELECT carid,
                                      sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
                            FROM tbl_fuel
                            GROUP BY carid) tbl_fuel ON tbl_fuel.carid = tbl_vehicle.carid
                            LEFT JOIN
                            (SELECT carid,
                                      sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
                            FROM tbl_maintenance
                            GROUP BY carid) tbl_maintenance ON tbl_maintenance.carid = tbl_vehicle.carid
                            WHERE tbl_fuel.sum_amount IS NOT NULL OR tbl_maintenance.sum_amount IS NOT NULL");
```

this how the script constructed to get total values in column:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = document.getElementById("expense_table"), sumVal=0;
for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
    sumVal=sumVal+ parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
}
console.log(sumVal);
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML="Total Expenses: " + sumVal;
```

this how I inserted the values in my database's table named tbl_fuel.

```
$result = $_POST["employee"];
            $result_explode=explode('|', $result);  
            $result = query("INSERT INTO tbl_fuel 
                (employee_id,
                carid,
                account_id,
                trip_date,
                invoice,
                up_date,
                previous,
                present,
                liter,
                amount,
                purpose,
                code,
                attachment,
                dateAdded) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                $result_explode[1],
                $_POST["platenumber"],
                $_POST["account_id"],
                $_POST["trip_date"], 
                $_POST["invoice"], 
                $_POST["up_date"], 
                $_POST["previous"], 
                $_POST["present"], 
                $_POST["liter"],  
                $_POST["amount"], 
                $_POST["purpose"],
                $_POST["code"],
                $target_file, 
                date("Y-m-d"));
```

this is the second SQL (tbl_maintenance in my database)

```
$result = $_POST["employee"];
            $result_explode=explode('|', $result);
            $result = query("INSERT INTO tbl_maintenance 
                (employee_id,
                carid,
                account_id,
                main_date,
                invoice,
                up_date,
                previous,
                present,
                particular,
                code,
                amount,
                purpose) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
                $result_explode[1],  
                $_POST["platenumber"], 
                $_POST["account_id"], 
                $_POST["main_date"], 
                $_POST["invoice"], 
                $_POST["up_date"], 
                $_POST["previous"], 
                $_POST["present"], 
                $_POST["particular"], 
                $_POST["code"], 
                $_POST["amount"], 
                $_POST["purpose"]);
```

if you notice, both table has the same attributes, carid and amount,
I want their value to be display monthly. the value of these tables were already combined using the first SQL state above.

Comment: Since it seems that you only need to display a table as a report, I would advice to use jQuery and datatables (https://datatables.net/). Datatables is going to make your life easier. It comes with a lot of features such as export to PDFs, sorting by column, searching, and much more. It is well supported and has full examples to your disposition. Trust me on this one.

Comment: thank for the respond sir

Comment: You welcome. Just increase press the arrow that will show up next to my message to give me a point if does help. :)